# Is it possible not to clamp data when using glReadPixels?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to develop a code where I load a 3d model with assimp, do stuff with the 3d coordinates and normals of verticies and then I want to retrieve my textures to CPU.

I tried using "glReadPixels" to retrieve the textures but my data is getting clamped between [0 1] as they describe in [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml).

An example of the textures I use :

```
    glGenTextures(1, &pos3d);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pos3d);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + gpos3dLayout, GL_TEXTURE_2D, pos3d, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

And then I retrieve using this:

```
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pos3d);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    std::vector<GLfloat> positions3d(width * height * 4); // 4 because of RGBA * 1 float
    glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, &positions3d[0]);
```

As I said, my values seems to be clamped between 0 and 1. So is there a way to disable this clamping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data are clamped, because the internal format of the texture which is attached to the color plane of the framebuffer is `GL_RGBA` (which is the same as `GL_RGBA8`). This format is a unsigned normalized fixed-point format and provides 8 bits for each color channel, where 0 represents 0.0 and all 8 bits set (255) represent 1.0.
This causes that the representation of the data in the data store of the texture is clamped. [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml) reads the data from the data store which is attached to the color plane of the frambuffer.

Change the internal format of the texture to a floating point format (e.g. `GL_RGBA16F`), when specifying a two-dimensional texture image by [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml):

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
```

---

When the pixel are read form the buffer, then they may are clamped to the range [0.0, 1.0].
This depends on the setting of [`glClampColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClampColor.xhtml).

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 18.2.8 Final Conversion](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf), page 535

> Read color clamping is controlled by calling
>
> `void ClampColor( enum target, enum clamp )`
>
> with target set to `CLAMP_READ_COLOR`. If clamp is `TRUE`, read color clamping is enabled; if clamp is `FALSE`, read color clamping is disabled. [...]
>   For a floating-point RGBA color, if type is `FLOAT` or `HALF_FLOAT`, each component is clamped to [0, 1] if read color clamping is enabled.

Note, in OpenGL ES the colors are clamped  in any case.

---

[`glGetTexImage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetTexImage.xhtml) is provided in desktop OpenGL only and doesn't clamp the colors.

Comment: I tried that and GL_RGBA32F but I'm still only getting clamped values. Could there be another problem?

Comment: @user6138759 What do you do in the shader program?

Comment: For the pos3d texture, once I load the 3D model, I load the 3D coords and my first shader does only  vec4(inPos, 1.0) to turn into RGBA. I use a sampler2D on the pos3d texture in other shaders but I do not modify the content.

Comment: @user6138759 Try [`glClampColor(GL_CLAMP_READ_COLOR, GL_FALSE)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClampColor.xhtml)

Comment: It doesn't change anything. However, when I used [glGetTexImage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glGetTexImage.xml) instead of glReadPixels , the results are not clamped. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @user6138759 Reading the specification [18.2.8 Final Conversion](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf) (page 643) says *"Read color clamping is controlled by calling ClampColor"* [...] *"For a floating-point RGBA color, if type is FLOAT or HALF_FLOAT, each component is clamped to [0, 1] if read color clamping is enabled"*. `glGetTexImage` doesn't clamp the color anyway.

Comment: @user6138759 I can't reproduce the issue. `glReadPixels` gives me the color in full range. If I turn on color clamp (`glClampColor( GL_CLAMP_READ_COLOR, GL_TRUE )`), then the range is limited to [0, 1 ] - as expected.

Comment: @user6138759 Your using OpenGL and not OpenGL ES isn't it? Probably, because `glGetTexImage` is provided by desktop OpenGL only.

Comment: Yes I'm using OpenGL desktop. I can't figure out why glClampColor isn't doing anything for me.